# Prevent access​ user collection in deployd js

Tags: node.js, express, deployd, dpd

Im using deployd js (http://deployd.com) as my backend api. I have created user collection and deployd automatically create REST API for me. I can access my user collection by http://localhost:8080/users URL. It returns all users as a JSON array.

Here you can find more about how to use user collection in deployd
http://docs.deployd.com/docs/users/creating-user-collections.html

Now I need to deny access this route to the outside or hide sensitive information. Because anyone can simply get all users in my application (without their password) by accessing this REST route. Anyone can get all users username, email, role ect.

Comment: @rckrd - I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

add this to onGet event

```
cancel("Forbidden access!", 403);
```

no one will be able to query the /users anymore